# How do I Increase Network Utilization in my USB Mobile Broadband?

Tags: internet, mobile-broadband

How do I increase network utilization in my USB Mobile Broadband? I have a USB mobile broadband and it says I have a link speed of 3Mbps but somehow, I can't fully utilize it. Is it possible to fully utilize it or even just the 50%? I'm running in Windows 7 64-bit.

Here's what my Task Manager is showing. In this, downloading 1 file through torrent and surfing:

http://imageshack.com/a/img841/7944/tv5hs.jpg

Comment: If your connection is being throttled there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: What do you mean throttled?

Comment: A connection can be throttled by decreasing your potential throughput if your service provider detects certain packets by using deep packet inspection.

Comment: Don't know if the connection is being throttled but sometimes the network utilization reaches 20-40% but right this past few weeks, the connection is very slow.

Comment: @snowpanda In other words, your USB interface is fast, but your carrier is slowing you down. It's like having a tiny trickle in a big water hose.